# AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead

Tags: java, lwjgl, openal

I'm coding to manage OpenAL in java using lwjgl 3 and when I create the ALContext with this line:

```
ALContext alContext = ALContext.create();
```

When I execute the console prints this advice

> AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz
>   instead

Any idea about whats wrong?

By the way, it's getting really hard coding with lwjgl 3, the only place I found some kind of guide is here [lwjgl github](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3)

Comment: Updating the driver (and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf) might fix it

Comment: Using windows, but the update of the driver didn't change anything.Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my ASUS desktop, I have Realtek HD Audio Manager setting the Default Audio format to `24Bits 44800 Hz`, thus my open AL applications are not able to request a `44100 Hz` device. Changing that default format to `44100` will help solve the problem.

I wish it could help, because it did take me a lot of time to figure this out!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @ManishDubey: read carefully, he provided a recipe based on its own experience, not a "I have this problem too" not-an-answer

Comment: This solved the advice for me. I was trying to avoid the advice to appearing in the users console, but I guess that the user will have to see it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Thank you so much. Please edit this if you can find a way around having to downgrade your laptops audio.

Answer (score 1):

On my Linux machine (*Ubuntu Server 18.04*), I too was seeing the error that said:

```
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
```

I was able to get rid of this error by modifying the file named: **/etc/openal/alsoft.conf**

In this file was this entry under the **[general]** section:

```
## frequency:
#  Sets the output frequency. If left unspecified it will try to detect a
#  default from the system, otherwise it will default to 44100.
#frequency =
```

I changed the `#frequency = line` to be: `frequency = 48000` and now I no longer get this error.